Где выполняется оперативная память гостевой ОС?
Подскажите, где реализуется оперативная память виртуальной винды: где то на физическом диске или в настоящей плашке ОЗУ?

Непонятно, что вы имеете в виду под терминами «выполняется» и «реализуется». Во время работы виртуальной машины её текущее состояние неизбежно вынуждено присутствовать в оперативной памяти, иначе непонятно как процессор мог бы с ней работать

Так то в ОЗУ, но если не будет хватать реальной оперативки, то как и с другими программами винда может начать сваповать не используемые в данный момент части ОЗУ на диск. Так что лучше, чтобы у винды хватало физической памяти на всё, включая виртуалку.

я все понял, спасибо

@CrazyElf а вот конкретно VirtualBox имеет привычку лочить память чтобы в своп не улетало

@andreymal Я не знал, что так можно )  Правда, если памяти на всё будет не хватать, то от того, что VB залочит свою память от свопования, в целом винде то лучше не станет. Тогда что-то другое в своп уйдёт, может быть более нужное для работы системы в данный момент )  Хотя я понимаю, что сама система, драйвера и прочее в своп не уйдут. Ну, короче, надо конкретную конфигурацию смотреть.
